# Thymeleaf and formatting a phone number HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to format a phone number that is being retrieved from a database and it is coming in like this xxxxxxxxxx and I have been trying to figure out how to format it so it appears as follows xxx-xxx-xxxx. If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thanks all

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're currently working with. Are you trying to format that number on the server or client side? In what language? How is "thymeleaf" relevant?

Comment: Are you certain that the data is always going to be in that form?  If not, you may want to take a look at Google's `libphonenumber`.  This can be more complex than it seems depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the phone number is stored in a variable called `str`

```
return str.substring(0,3)+'-'+str.substring(3,6)+'-'+str.substring(6)
```

Comment: Thank you Our-Benefactors. I honestly did not even think of doing that but it worked.  Appreciate your help everyone

Comment: @RichSanchez please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

I created a wrapping TagLib/ExpressionFactory to simplify the usage of Google's `libphonenumber` in Thymeleaf:

```
<a th:href="|tel:${#phoneNumber.format('044 111 22 33', 'CH', 'E164')}|" 
th:text="${#phoneNumber.format('044 111 22 33', 'CH', 'NATIONAL')}"></a>
```

My Blog post [Formatting phone numbers using libphonenumber in Thymeleaf](https://www.kobelnet.ch/2020/01/08/formatting-phone-numbers-using-libphonenumber-in-thymeleaf) explains the integration/usage.